# iphone - facebook login and post problem

Tags: iphone, facebook, authentication

I'm integrating facebook in my iphone app.
I placed a button "Post" and when clicked, its showing "Facebook Login" view. I'm entering the credentials. Then did login delegate, i'm posting the message. Now,its showing the message view with two buttons at the bottom "Skip" and "Publish". "Publish" is working fine. When "Skip" is clicked, its showing me the login screen again (without any details). On the top left I can click "X" and close it. But why is the login screen showing again?

Do I've to close the view explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

No Need.See this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app) and check out the sample code.

All the best.

Comment: I've seen the tutorial. But still I see the same problem.